# Response.Cookies.Add wait for confirmation?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I have a page where I am using a cookie to store a token.

If the cookie is found, the page loads one way,
If not, the page is sent into authenticate mode.

The problem is, if the cookie isn't found, and I send the page into auth mode, and the user hits submit, nine times out of ten the cookie isn't found on postback and the user has to wait a second or two to refresh the page at which point the cookie is found.

Can I wait to confirm the cookie on button_click before I postback?

**Code**

```
    public HttpCookie Cookie()
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("testcookie");
        cookie = Request.Cookies["testcookie"];

        return cookie ?? null;
    }

    var cookie = Cookie();
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        login.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        login.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void IDButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newCookie = new HttpCookie("testcookie");
        Response.Cookies.Add(newCooke);
    }
```

Comment: Something seams to miss in your code : on button click you have to add the new cookie to the Response

Comment: Just added that. It was in the code, just missed the copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be having a problem with [ASP.NET's page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). You are setting your cookie on the Button's Click event, but by then the page has already loaded, and your display isn't updated.

Perhaps you could extract your display code into a new method, and call the method during the Buttons's click event.

I have included an example below, which is a page that contains a `Literal` (displays 'Yes' or 'No' if a cookie is set) and a `Button` to set it;

```
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralCookie" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSetCookie" Text="Set cookie" runat="server"
  OnClick="ButtonSetCookieClick" />
```

And here is the code behind;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    UpdateDisplayBasedOnCookie();
  }
}

public void UpdateDisplayBasedOnCookie()
{
  LiteralCookie.Text = Request.Cookies["TestCookie"] == null ? "No" : "Yes";
}

protected void ButtonSetCookieClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SetCookie();
  UpdateDisplayBasedOnCookie();
}

private void SetCookie()
{
  HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("TestCookie");
  myCookie.Values.Add("Username", "Matt");
  myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);

  Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

So by clicking the button, the `Literal` changes from 'No' to 'Yes', indicating that it's found the cookie on the POST. I hope this is clear.

Please let me know if I can help further,

Matt